# How to calculate the change between rows in a grouped data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
    A tibble: 47,898 x 4
# Groups:   countyfips [1,774]
   countyfips day_month_year new_case_rate_07da case_rate
        <dbl> <date>                      <dbl>     <dbl>
 1       1001 2020-01-12                      0         0
 2       1001 2020-01-19                      0         0
 3       1001 2020-01-26                      0         0
 4       1001 2020-02-02                      0         0
 5       1001 2020-02-09                      0         0
 6       1001 2020-02-16                      0         0
 7       1001 2020-02-23                      0         0
 8       1001 2020-03-01                      0         0
 9       1001 2020-03-08                      0         0
10       1001 2020-03-15                      0         0
# … with 47,888 more rows
```

I would like to calculate the change between the case rates for each county each week.

I have tried the following code:

```
Affinity_County_Weekly.csv %>% group_by(countyfips) %>% mutate(change_vs_last_week_case_rate = (case_rate-lag(case_rate))/lag(case_rate)
```

But the output for that has been zero for all rows (even though the values in rows after 10 are not zero).

How would you try to fix this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: Coul you share a bigger portion of your dataset (so it includes not zero values) and in a reproducible way (for example, the output of `dput(Affinity_County_Weekly)`)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [diff](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/diff) which computes the lagged difference of vector or matrix `x` between `lag` rows (default 1).

Take the following example:

```
d <- data.frame(cases = c(4, 2, 3, 10, 0, 100))
diff(d$cases)
# [1]  -2   1   7 -10 100
```

Effectively it creates a new vector that calculates the difference between 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4, etc. This is also why the result only has 5 values, as there is no index 0 to subtract from index 1. (Note that with a different `lag`, there may be fewer values)

So depending on what you want the value in the first row to be, you can append a column as follows:

```
d$newCases <- c(0, diff(d$cases))
#   cases newCases
# 1     4        0
# 2     2       -2
# 3     3        1
# 4    10        7
# 5     0      -10
# 6   100      100
```

In your specific problem, I imagine this should work:

```
Affinity_County_Weekly.csv %>% group_by(countyfips) %>% mutate(change_vs_last_week_case_rate = c(0, diff(case_rate))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The code worked and now I have the differences between the case rates. But when I try to calculate the percentage change using the following code: `x <- Affinity_County_Weekly.csv %>% group_by(countyfips) %>% mutate(growth_case_rate = c(0, diff(case_rate))) %>% mutate(change_case_rate = growth_case_rate/lag(case_rate))` R just calculates the growth_case_rate divided by the case_rate in the same row: `case_rate growth_case_rate change_case_rate1      10.7             10.7            1    
2      21.5             10.8            0.502`

Comment: From testing I'm not quite sure what `lag` does, but you could try prepending a value at the beginning of the column and deleting the last value, so it effectively shifts every value one back (`c(0, case_rate[-length(case_rate)]`). What should the value be if dividing by 0?